# Silverlight Behaviours Triggers Actions tutorial request

Tags: .net, silverlight, triggers, behavior, action

I am interested in understanding Silverlight **Behaviours-Triggers-Actions** in depth. I found a few blogs which gave me basic information about them, but couldn't find a comprehensive reference. Can someone kindly point me to some good material ?

Thank you.

Comment: any help anybody ? I am still not able to find a comprehensive reference....

Answer (score 1):

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Behaviors-and-Triggers-in-Silverlight-3.aspx